# PHP grouping array

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I know this is has been asked and I have tried to follow what I have found on other post but for some reason I can't get it to work.  I am parsing multiple xml files that contain tv programming. I am trying to group all shows by times.  This is what I have.

```
  foreach ($items as $load){
   $contents[]= simplexml_load_file($load['guide']); //LOAD XML EACH CHANNEL INTO ARRAY
   }
  echo "COUNT OF CONTENT. . . ".count($contents)."<br>";  //SHOULD BE 36 TIME SLOTS
  foreach($contents as $content){ //BUILD MAIN ARRAYs
            $start[]=$content->programme['start'];
            $title[]=$content->programme->title;
            $desc[]=$content->programme->desc;
    }   
            $i=0;
            foreach($start as $a=>$b){ 
                    if($b==$start[$i]){
                                    $garray=array(
                                    'start'=> $start[$i],
                                    'title'=> $title[$i],
                                    'desc'=> $desc[$i],
                                    );
                                    $i++;

                                }else{
                                $i++;
                        }                   

                }
```

I anticipate a total of 36 values in $contents. I will loop thru each $contents creating an array for start, title and desc. Then I want to loop thru each $start to group all $title and $desc under it's corresponding $start.  For some reason I can't make this work with what I have. If I run it as shown and check the count of $garray I have 3. I know for example the first $start I encounter should have 18 titles under the one $start.  I would like to have it in the following format based on the start, each array would have one start each but multiple titles and descs. I anticipate saving the final $garray to an array file to be accessed by other programs. It could be saved to xml if need be.  Any help greatly appreciated.

```
  array1(
      0=> 'start', 'title 1', 'desc 1',
      1=> 'start','title 2', 'desc 2',
      2=> 'start', 'title 3', 'desc 3',
      );
```

Here is an example of the xml.  Each file contains info like this, there maybe multiple entries in each xml.  I am only interested in the start, title and desc.  I can parse each out but have been unable to group by the same value of start.

```
<programme start="20160122140000 -0500" stop="20160122150000 -0500"                  channel="I396.20453.schedulesdirect.org">

    <title lang="en">FABLife</title>

    <sub-title lang="en">Mark Cuban's Top 5 Secrets to Making Millions; Top 5 Must-Haves for 2016; Can Your Memorabilia Make You Rich?; Playroom Decorating on a Dime</sub-title>

    <desc lang="en">Mark Cuban (``Shark Tank''); top five must-haves; collectors try to guess the prices of celebrity memorabilia; creating a high-end playroom and eliminating toy clutter without breaking the bank.</desc>

    <credits>

        <guest>Mark Cuban</guest>

        <presenter>Tyra Banks</presenter>

        <presenter>Chrissy Teigen</presenter>

        <presenter>Joe Zee</presenter>

        <presenter>Lauren Makk</presenter>

        <presenter>Leah Ashley</presenter>

    </credits>

    <date>20160111</date>

    <category lang="en">Cooking</category>

    <category lang="en">Fashion</category>

    <category lang="en">House/garden</category>

    <category lang="en">How-to</category>

    <category lang="en">Series</category>

    <category lang="en">Talk</category>

    <episode-num system="onscreen">1074</episode-num>

    <episode-num system="dd_progid">EP02234030.0074</episode-num>

    <video>

        <aspect>16:9</aspect>

        <quality>HDTV</quality>

    </video>

    <audio>

        <stereo>stereo</stereo>

    </audio>

    <previously-shown start="20160111000000" />

    <subtitles type="teletext" />

    <rating system="VCHIP">

        <value>TV-PG</value>

    </rating>

</programme>
```

Comment: just use a single foreach and then load the file from there, after that just traverse the parent xml, get your values, then gather one single batch to push into the final container

Comment: Not sure I follow completely. I can move the close brace for the main foreach to end and incorporate all code in the main loop where the each xml is loaded, but don't I still need the foreach statements to traverse the $contents and then the $start array?

Comment: to put it simply step by step, first, use foreach to load each file, just assign it into a variable `$contents` (don't push it inside an array), then another foreach to traverse `$contents` for desired values, gather, then assign it finally, `$final_data[] = array('start' => $content->programme->whatevervalues, 'others' => ....)` and so on

Comment: So you need to combine, group, and sort multiple XML files and can even return a final XML? Then I advise using XSLT (the language dedicated to manipulate XML files) which PHP comes equipped with an XSLT 1.0 processor. Please post an example XML. No looping or arrays will be used!

Comment: Thanks Parfait, I'll post xml example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XSLT 1.0, you can combine multiple XML files using the [document()](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/func_document.asp) function (i.e., all 36 of your TV xmls) and then group the large xml in a process known as [Muenchian Method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) which uses a grouping key, here being the `@start` attribute. However, the above two tasks will require two transformations (of course the xslt gurus can do it in one!). Do note from your post, you do not show a root xml tag to wrap `<programme>` nodes. A generalized `<root>` is added below:

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl or .xslt file)* - first transformation

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="document('TV1.xml')/root/*"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="document('TV2.xml')/root/*"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="document('TV3.xml')/root/*"/>
      ...
      <xsl:copy-of select="document('TV36.xml')/root/*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>  

</xsl:transform>
```

Should you happen to have an open-ended number of XMLs, you can dynamically create XSLT as a PHP string (adding the `xsl:copy-of` lines above via a PHP loop) and parse it with `loadXML()` instead of `load()` as used in PHP below.

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl or .xslt file)* - second transformation

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="startkey" match="programme" use="@start" />

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each select="programme[generate-id()= generate-id(key('startkey',@start)[1])]">
        <start>
          <xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of select="@start"/></xsl:attribute>   
          <xsl:for-each select="key('startkey', @start)">
            <xsl:copy>
              <title><xsl:value-of select="title"/></title>
              <description><xsl:value-of select="desc"/></description>
            </xsl:copy>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </start>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>    

</xsl:transform>
```

**PHP** Script *(load and process both pairs of XML and XSLT files)*

```
/******* FIRST TRANSFORMATION *******/
$doc1 = new DOMDocument();
$doc1->load('TV1.xml');

$xsl1 = new DOMDocument;
$xsl1->load('FirstXSLTScript.xsl');

// Configure the transformer
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl1); 

// Transform XML source
$combineXml = $proc->transformToXML($doc1);

/******* SECOND TRANSFORMATION *******/
$doc2 = new DOMDocument();
$doc2->loadXML($combineXml);

$xsl2 = new DOMDocument;
$xsl2->load('SecondXSLTScript.xsl');

// Configure the transformer
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl2); 

// Transform XML source
$finalXml = $proc->transformToXML($doc2);

// Save output to file
$xmlfile = 'FinalOutput.xml';
file_put_contents($xmlfile, $finalXml);
```

**Final Output** *(adding other example data for demonstration)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <start value="20160122140000 -0500">
    <programme>
      <title>FABLife</title>
      <description>Mark Cuban (``Shark Tank''); top five must-haves; collectors try to guess the prices of celebrity memorabilia; creating a high-end playroom and eliminating toy clutter without breaking the bank.</description>
    </programme>
    <programme>
      <title>Blacklist</title>
      <description>Elizabeth 'Liz' Keen, a new FBI profiler has her entire life uprooted when a mysterious criminal, Raymond Reddington, on the FBI's Top Ten Most Wanted List turns himself in and insists on speaking to her.</description>
    </programme>
    <programme>
      <title>Persons Of Interest</title>
      <description>An ex-assassin and a wealthy programmer save lives via a surveillance AI that sends them the identities of civilians involved in impending crimes. However, the details of the crimes--including the civilians' roles--are left a mystery.</description>
    </programme>
  </start>
  <start value="20160142140000 -0500">
    <programme>
      <title>Sense8</title>
      <description>A group of people around the world are suddenly linked mentally, and must find a way to survive being hunted by those who see them as a threat to the world's order.</description>
    </programme>
    <programme>
      <title>Scandal</title>
      <description>A former White House Communications Director starts her own crisis management firm only to realize her clients are not the only ones with secrets.</description>
    </programme>
  </start>
  <start value="20160152140000 -0500">
    <programme>
      <title>Graceland</title>
      <description>A rookie FBI agent is sent to a house for undercover agents in Southern California, where he is trained by a former legend FBI agent.</description>
    </programme>
  </start>
</root>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. I was attempting it with foreach loops I had found in other post but just couldn't get it to work completely. As for the root xml, I think when I copied the xml over I neglected to included that. Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: Parfait, couple of questions. How does the script know what xml files to load. For instance in php you have load doc tv1.xml, would I change this to the name of my first xml file? Also do I need to save the php and xls files in the same directory as the xmls?

Comment: I guess I should rephrase the questions, Would I need to use a foreach to loop thru each xml file to put in the $doc->load(tv1.xml) line, replacing tv1.xml with name of each xml to be transormed? Also do the script need to be saved in the same folder as the xml files to be processed?

Comment: In first xslt, `document()` points to named XML files -change those to actual names. In fact, any one of the XML files can be used as source in first transform as only root tag is read (no content since eventually it is copied over with all others). While PHP can be in another directory. All XML files must be together.

Comment: No looping is needed. The first file, `tv1.xml` serves as just initial source and is transformed by appending all others to it.

Comment: Excellent, worked like a charm. Thanks again for the time and lesson. Never would have considered doing it soley in xml,

Comment: Fantastic! Yes, XSLT is a special-purpose language (sadly hardly used as many programmers go your original route with complex looping). And all general-purpose languages (C#, Java, Python, PHP, Perl, VB) have libraries for XSLT. But I'll be there to fight the good cause. No one thinks twice about the other special purpose language called SQL!

Comment: Your correct on that. I'm sure somebody more versed in php could have done it with less loops, but with the xslt no loops.  I have actually set it up to use one loop at first of php to read my channel list and create the first xlst based on the channels in my list so I only have to modify in my channel list file one time, it does the rest. Keep up the good fight.

Comment: Parfait, is there any particular xml writer for php you recommend?

Comment: I think the standard [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) works well with its `createElement()`, `createAttribute()` and `appendChild()` methods, including namespace handling.

Comment: Parfait, is there a way to have the XSLT take into consideration and "odd" datetime? As you see in the start element we have a value of 20160122140000 (1-22-2016 2:00:00 PM). I noticed we I run the script and it hits something like 20160122142000 (1-22-2016 2:20;00 PM) it moves this entry to end of the file or at least after all full hour times.

Comment: You can [substring](http://zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/Output/function_substring.html) the start time: `substring(@start, 1,10)` and leave out mins and secs. Replace all `@starts` with it in xslt script.

Comment: Is it possible to add a sort from earliest to latest on the start value in the finaloutput xml file?

Comment: I think I got it.   <xsl:sort select="@start"/>  added into xslt.